# attempting to print multiple lines in a function without generating the 'none' output

Tags: python

I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game where the board is printed containing the number pad to make it easier to understand where you are selecting on the game board.

please see the below function and actual example of this output:

```
def display_board(board):
    print('')
    print(board[7],'|', board[8], '|', board[9])
    print('--|---|--')
    print(board[4],'|', board[5], '|', board[6])
    print('--|---|--')
    print(board[1],'|', board[2], '|', board[3])
    print('')
```

the idea is to then take the user input (either 'X' or 'O') and throw it up on the board. however I cannot seem to make it work without outputting 'none' at the bottom. is there a way to avoid this for aesthetics?

below is an example with the input being selected and the character being added in its place:

```
Player 1, please select your game position: 1

7 | 8 | 9
--|---|--
4 | 5 | 6
--|---|--
x | 2 | 3

None
```

the comments were looking for more...I just did not want to overload the question but here is the rest of it:

```
def the_meat(first_marker,player1,player2):
    game_board=['#','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
    if first_marker ==True: #this means that player 1 is first
        while first_marker is True:
            current_board=display_board(game_board)
            print(current_board)
            position_select=False
            while position_select==False:
                move=input('Player 1, please select your game position: ')
                position_select=free_space(move)
            player_move=int(move)
            game_board[player_move]=player1
            current_board=display_board(game_board)
            print(current_board)
```

Comment: Not quite sure. Your function doesn't print None, but it does return None. Are you printing the function display_board itself? That would print a None. I don't think you are showing us all the code.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code as well?

Comment: The display_board function does not print `none`. The `none` must be occurring elsewhere. Are you returning from this function, are you making any calls after this which may return `none`? Are you calling `print(display_board(board))`?

Comment: I have added the code that actually deals with the table, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't put a return statement in your function it will return by default `None`.

So, if you do: `print(display_board(board))` it will execute the print statements you defined in your function and then it will print the returned value of this function (in this case `None`)

---

You're calling `print` function on the variable `current_board`, according to these lines:

```py
current_board=display_board(game_board)
print(current_board)
```

That's not necessary, just call the `display_board` function and you'll have the behavior you're seeking.

So, your function would be:

```py
def the_meat(first_marker,player1,player2):
    game_board=['#','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
    if first_marker ==True: #this means that player 1 is first
        while first_marker is True:
            current_board=display_board(game_board)
            print(current_board)
            position_select=False
            while position_select==False:
                move=input('Player 1, please select your game position: ')
                position_select=free_space(move)
            player_move=int(move)
            game_board[player_move]=player1
            display_board(game_board)
```

Comment: hi, thank you. I have added more pieces of my code for clarity, but I am calling the function in that way and it still seems print none. is there any specific change you are seeing in the new code I added?

Comment: @pepperjack I edited my answer so you can see how you can get the behavior you want (no 'None' statement)